# How to show progress bar in android and hide when content loads

Tags: android, sms

Below is my code. Please help me to add progress bar in my android application. My app is a type of messaging app and I want that circular progress bar should show when I press the send SMS button and progress bar should disable when it receives sms. Please review my code and suggest me how to do. Please mention complete detail because I am a beginner so understanding in shortcut is tough for me. Thankyou

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btnSendSMS;
        EditText enteredNum;
        IntentFilter intentFilter;
        private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //---display the SMS received in the TextView---
                TextView SMSes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                SMSes.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("sms"));
            }
        };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //---intent to filter for SMS messages received---
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enteredNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterDetail);
                assert enteredNum != null;
                sendSMS("51522", "HELP " + enteredNum.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ","").toUpperCase());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
//---register the receiver---
        registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
//---unregister the receiver---
        unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: judging by the code you have written, it should be pretty easy for you to add a loading animation. Things might be diff if this is not your code and you dont know how it works.

Comment: @Shubhank can you please add progress bar code in my existing code and paste it back in comment ?

Comment: that will move to being a broad requirement, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: So what it is ? @Shubhank

Comment: its a place where programmers help each other out. Questions are expected to be well detailed and researched and with the poster showing effort. You are not showing any effort and simply asking for code which won't work.

Comment: I tried to add codes myself but that is not working for me. So I decided to ask out for help. And I said to add codes in my codes and send me because I tried adding codes from android developer website also but that even not worked for me. M not asking for full code. I want only for progress bar and actually I already have codes, but as I didnot worked for me I wanted to make sure it will work perfectly if any experienced coder will see my codes give me codes. @Shubhank

Comment: you should show what didnt worked then. you never told us what you tried

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_activity);

         mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

         // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                     mProgressStatus = doWork();

Comment: mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                         }
                     });

Comment: please update your question with the code. that way we can see where you had this code and suggest changes

Comment: that only I want to know where to place this codes

Answer (score 1):

You could add a **ProgressBar** element inside your activity_main.xml

Then, inside your Activity, you can use the property **setVisibility()** for show (*View.VISIBLE*) your ProgressBar and hide (*View.GONE*) your layout or content.

[More information here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Good luck!

Comment: This is the best way to do it - as this will prevent any resources from being allocated to the View. Good answer!

Comment: @Jose can you please add progress bar code in my existing code and paste it back in comment ?